# Is there an adaptor/app that can connect an iPhone to a Canon DSLR as an external monitor?

Tags: canon, iphone, adapter

I love the swivel monitor on my Canon 60D but as I am planning to upgrade to a camera with a fixed screen I am also looking into some small external monitors with swivel capabilities.  I saw some interesting options from Sony and Swivi but they are all around $350-$400.

**Is there any way I can hookup my existing iPhone 4 and connect it with a Canon DSLR camera HDMI output.**  I Don't need to control the camera options but I would like the be able to see the live view on the phone.

Edit: What I am looking for is a setup similar to one shown in [THIS video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vasHnIH8jE) but for using iPhone

Comment: What is the new camera? AFAIK, only some of recently released cameras, such as Canon 6D and Nikon D600, offer cheap WiFi option which can be used to connect the camera to iPhone, from there you can control the camera too.

Comment: Sort of close is the EyeFi card option, but it's after the fact, not a live view. On the plus side, it's wireless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Regarding *your* edit. **That is NOT HDMI output.** What you are looking at is **tethered shooting**. It is available directly for Android [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.dslrcontroller). For now on iOS, you need an intermediate computer to do the relay and [this app](http://www.ononesoftware.com/products/dslr-camera-remote/).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

If that DSLR is the [Canon EOS 6D](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/canon/6d), you just need the Canon App (iOS and Android) and will be connected wirelessly. You will be able to see the Live-View and even control the camera.

For a wired-connection via HDMI, you would need a device attached to your phone. I've never seen such thing and it would probably not be cheap either.

Comment: Either 6D or 5D m2. Not 100% sure yet. I do 90% of my focusing via live view so the rendition would need to be very smooth.  I've read some preliminary things about the wifi connection and Live view appears to be jerky. (understandably these reports are not yet very reliable)

Comment: They cannot be reliable yet because AFAIK they have not shipped production 6Ds yet. Expect them closer to the availability date.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have some particular hang-up that it has to be your iPhone, the gadget you're looking for is called a *field monitor*.  Many are available in a wide variety of price ranges, and most have HDMI inputs.

Comment: I was hoping to utilize the gadget I already have without having to purchase another one.

Answer (score 2):

**DSLRCameraRemote**, as linked above, is no longer supported by onOne Software nor is it available via the iTunes store.

Alternatives? There are none.

Recently I downloaded **xRemote DSLR** as it also uses a camera tethered to a computer AND then wireless connection to the iphone/ipad, like **DSLRCameraRemote** but it has no live view. For me, this is a critical issue, as Liveview allows for compositional control especially when setting up product or flat fashion-sets photographs.

The alternative identified by onOne rune to a few hundred dollars!?!  While the app that onOne supplied, well the one I bought cost 50 dollars or there abouts. 50 bucks! my system craps out and I lose it all, I can't do shite.

As it stands, as of 23 May 2013, if you want remote wireless tethered control of your camera then you need to purchase a hardware based wireless connectivity solution for your specific camera AND then use the associated iPhone/iPad app to remotely control your camera. This is a significant backward step for those that have been previously using the onOne software solution.

As my old Physics Teacher used to say, "tough bunnies!"

Answer (score 0):

There's also the IOS app FieldMonitor by Adam Wilt (which now supports Canon cameras), with a caveat: it works via wifi (not HDMI), so (like Canon Camera Connect) it is expected to have a little latency; differently from Canon Camera Connect, though, it displays full-screen video from your Canon DSLR camera to your iPhone.